# Using ifelse change the result of my calculus

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr

I have a dataset corresponding to different trials in which are tested different treatments. Some trials include a Control group, some do not.

Here is an example where there is a Control group only in the trial 1:

```
data = data.frame(trial = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
                  treatment = c("control", "b", "b", "c"),
                  value = c(97.2, 99.3, 85.51, 85.01))
```

When a trial include a Control group, I want to make the ratio between the treatments of this trial and the Control of this trial. I first filtered all the trial with a Control group and it worked well:

```
data %>%
    filter(trial == 1) %>%
    group_by(trial) %>%
    summarise(treatment = treatment, 
              r = value / value[which(treatment == "control")])
```

But when I tried to do it without filtering the trials and using the `ifelse()` function, I got unexpected result, the ratio was always equals to 1 (or `NA` when no Control group).

```
data %>%
    group_by(trial) %>%
    summarise(treatment = treatment, 
              r = ifelse("control" %in% treatment, value / value[which(treatment == "control")], NA))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need two corrections -

1. You need `mutate` instead of `summarise` if you want to keep the length of dataframe consistent.
2. `"control" %in% treatment` gives output of length 1. Even if you change it to `treatment %in% "control"` it will still give incorrect result since the condition is wrong itself.

Here is a shorter solution.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(trial) %>%
  mutate(r = value/value[match("control", treatment)])

#  trial treatment value     r
#  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 control    97.2  1   
#2     1 b          99.3  1.02
#3     2 b          85.5 NA   
#4     2 c          85.0 NA
```

We are using `match` because of two reasons here -

1. `match` ensures that you will always get 1 number even if you have two "control" for a `trial`. Even if it is highly unlikely it is good to be sure.
2. You can let go of `ifelse` because `match` would by default return `NA` if "control" does not exist.

---

As per new syntax you can use `.by` -

```
data %>%
  mutate(r = value/value[match("control", treatment)], .by = trial)
```

Comment: The new syntax does not seem to work in that case, it gives me unexpected result.

Answer (score 2):

@RonakShah has explained why your code fails, and I also prefer his `match()` solution. Another option that minimally modifies your code is to replace `ifelse()` with `if...else...`

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(trial) %>%
  mutate(r = if("control" %in% treatment) value/value[treatment == "control"] else NA)

# # A tibble: 4 × 4
# # Groups:   trial [2]
#   trial treatment value     r
#   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 control    97.2  1   
# 2     1 b          99.3  1.02
# 3     2 b          85.5 NA   
# 4     2 c          85.0 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution with `by`.

```r
with(data, by(data[-1], trial, \(X) {
  X$value <- X$value/X$value[match("control", X$treatment)]
  X
})) |> array2DF()
#>     trial treatment    value
#> 1       1   control 1.000000
#> 1.1     1         b 1.021605
#> 2       2         b       NA
#> 2.1     2         c       NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>